# Distinguish objects by different fields for different contexts

Tags: java, java-8, unique, equals, equality

Let say there is such immutable class:

```
public class Foo {
    private final Long id;
    private final String name;
    private final LocalDate date;

    public Foo(Long id, String name, LocalDate date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Foo foo = (Foo) o;
        return Objects.equals(getId(), foo.getId()) &&
                Objects.equals(getName(), foo.getName()) &&
                Objects.equals(getDate(), foo.getDate());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId(), getName(), getDate());
    }
}
```

There is a collection of objects of this class. In some cases, it is required to distinguish only by name and in some cases by name and date.

So pass collection to `java.util.Set<Foo>` or create java 8 `Stream<Foo>` calling `.distinct()` method is not working for this case.
I know it is possible to distinguish using `TreeSet` and `Comparator`. It looks like this:

```
private Set<Foo> distinct(List<Foo> foos, Comparator<Foo> comparator) {
    TreeSet<Foo> treeSet = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
    treeSet.addAll(foos);
    return treeSet;
}
```

usage:

```
distinct(foos, Comparator.comparing(Foo::getName)); // distinct by name
distinct(foos, Comparator.comparing(Foo::getName).thenComparing(Foo::getDate)); // distinct by name and date
```

But I think that is not a good way to do it.
What's the most elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: What makes you think this is not a good way to do it?

Comment: @duffymo, Because equals() and hashCode() are supposed to solve this problem and comparator is more about sorting elements.

Comment: I'd say this is actually the best way to do this, `equals` should check for equality. If you want to compare items  according to different qualities, you use different `Comparator`s

Comment: Yes, by all means.  Give two separate Comparator instances.  They can live outside the class they check.

Comment: I agree with @Chirlo - this is the best way to do it.  You aren't thinking about the solution properly.

Comment: Except you just use a TreeSet instead of a TreeMap. But what is the use-case exactly? I can't remember a single time where I thought: OK, I have 1000 persons, and I want only persons with distinct names, whatever their first name, date of birth and ID is (I'll just pick whichever comes first). I would understand if you wanted a Set<String> containing distinct names, or a Map<String, List<Person>> containing all the persons by their name, but distinct persons per name?

Answer (score 3):

First, let's consider your current approach, then I'll show a better alternative.

Your current approach is succinct, yet uses a `TreeMap` when all you need is a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). If you are OK with the `O(nlogn)` complexity imposed by the red/black tree structure of `TreeMap`, I would only change your current code to:

```
public static <T> Set<T> distinct(
        Collection<? extends T> list, 
        Comparator<? super T> comparator) {

    Set<T> set = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
    set.addAll(list);
    return set;
}
```

Note that I've made your method generic and static, so that it can be used in a generic way for any collection, no matter the type of its elements. I've also changed the first argument to `Collection`, so that it can be used with more data structures.

Also, `TreeSet` still has `O(nlogn)` time complexity because it uses a `TreeMap` as its backing structure.

---

The usage of `TreeSet` has 3 disadvantages: first, it sorts your elements according to the passed `Comparator` (maybe you don't need this); second, time complexity is `O(nlogn)` (which might be way too much if all you require is to have distinct elements); and third, it returns a `Set` (which might not be the type of collection the caller needs).

So, here's another approach that returns a `Stream`, which you can then collect to the data-structure you want:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> distinctBy(
        Collection<? extends T> list, 
        Function<? super T, ?>... extractors) {

    Map<List<Object>, T> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();  // preserves insertion order
    list.forEach(e -> {
        List<Object> key = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.asList(extractors)
                .forEach(f -> key.add(f.apply(e)));    // builds key
        map.merge(key, e, (oldVal, newVal) -> oldVal); // keeps old value
    });
    return map.values().stream();
}
```

This converts every element of the passed collection to a list of objects, according to the extractor functions passed as the varargs argument.

Then, each element is put into a `LinkedHashMap` with this key and merged by means of preserving the initially put value (change this as per your needs).

Finally, a stream is returned from the values of the map, so that the caller can do whatever she wants with it.

*Note:* this approach requires that all the objects returned by the extractor functions implement the `equals` and `hashCode` methods consistently, so that the list formed by them can be safely used as the key of the map.

Usage:

```
List<Foo> result1 = distinctBy(foos, Foo::getName)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

Set<Foo> result2 = distinctBy(foos, Foo::getName, Foo::getDate)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Very slick.  I am confused by the merge since this will delete items from output.  But I guess if that's what the customer wants, then that's what the customer gets.

Comment: Hi @Jose, actually the idea is to not keep duplicates, according to the desired criteria.

Comment: You could also use Arrays.stream(extractors).forEach(...) if you just want to forEach an array. (I don't know if Array::stream's result's forEach() implementation is in any way more performant than the forEach() from Array::asList's result, though).

Comment: @srborlongan I wouldn't create a stream just to directly use `forEach`. But that line (and the immediately previous one) might be rewritten using `Arrays.stream` along with `map` and `collect`, something like this: `List<Object> key = Arrays.stream(extractors).map(f -> f.apply(e)).collect(Collectors.toList())`. I prefer the way I did it in my answer, though, but this is a valid alternative, and I guess at the end it's a matter of taste.